# How to build numpy for Py4A?

Tags: android, python, numpy

As you have already understood, I can't build numpy as a module for Py4A.
[Here's](http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/wiki/BuildingModules) an instruction but I still can't make it.
I installed [Toolchain](http://code.google.com/p/python-for-android/wiki/Toolchain_Installation), because I downloaded Android NDK and entered these 3 bash commands.

Here's a [screenshot](http://s61.radikal.ru/i173/1209/2c/fcfb8b61fa2e.png) of numpy folder. I don't know what to do next.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed the py4a module, then add

```
from py4a import patch_distutils
patch_distutils()
```

to `setup.py`, add the `setup.cfg` and now:

```
python setup.py configure
python setup.py build
```